# How can I resize a div by dragging an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, resizable

I have a slight problem here and maybe I can find someone who has dealt with this problem in the past.

How can I resize a div while dragging an image?

I'm using jQuery ui resizable and draggable.

Here's a live URL: http://railmedia.ro/test/

I am trying to figure out if resizing the div by dragging the brush is possible. The needed behaviour is something like a progress bar, except it needs to be done manually rather than automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use events dragg to resize container div, like as , it only grow it ..

```
            $(function() {
            $(".basecoat").resizable({maxWidth:598, ghost:true});
            $(".basecoat img.brush").draggable({
  start: function() {

    getCurrentPositionContainer= getOffset($(".basecoat"));

    limitX=getCurrentPositionContainer.left;

    limitY=getCurrentPositionContainer.top;

  },
  drag: function() {

    getCurrentPositionDraggable = getOffset($(".basecoat img.brush"));

    toLimitX=getCurrentPositionDraggable.left;

    toLimitY=getCurrentPositonDraggable.top;


    if(toLimitX>=limitX){

      currentWidth= $(".basecoat").width;

      $(".basecoat").width=currentWidth+10;

    }

    if(toLimitY>=limitY){
       currentHeight= $(".basecoat").height;

      $(".basecoat").height=currentHeight+10;
    }

    //set function to less 

  },
  stop: function() {
     //set any function like stop,
  }
}
);


function getOffset( el ) {
var _x = 0;
var _y = 0;
while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
    _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
    _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
    el = el.offsetParent;
}
return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately the code you provided doesn't actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I have found a CSS problem that did the trick for me. I expanded the resizable trigger's area with this single line:

```
.ui-resizable-e {width:67px;}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rmuser/MZWKr/4/